# Vicidial 3-way call transfer issue

Tags: voip, asterisk

I m having vicidial and working fine.
VERSION: 2.4-364a | Asterisk 1.4.44 | Single Server | No Extra Software After Installation | CentOS release 5.5

We are having one query related to call flow. I want to know the actual flow of below call. How and which file gets executed:

1. Agent gets outbound call connected with client.
2. Agent calls other supervisor by clicking on Transfer Button => Dial with Customer.
3. Once the supervisor picks up the call, all 3 will be in conference.
4. Now, agent will hangup the call by clicking 3-way leave button.

Here, when agent clicks on Dial with Customer, then the manager_send.php gets executed. This manager_send.php file fires Originate command to asterisk.

In vicidial.php file - line no 4241 :

**

> {agent_dialed_type='XFER_OVERRIDE';} // due to a bug in Asterisk,
>   these call variables do not actually work call_variables =
>   '__vendor_lead_code=' + document.vicidial_form.vendor_lead_code.value
>   + ',__lead_id=' + document.vicidial_form.lead_id.value;

**

Can we set our own variable? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

The lead_id is encoded in the transfer and used to open the same lead on the manager screen that was open on the client side. 
This way you can pass information using the vicidial_list table and its fields from the fronter to the closer. 
If you want to use warm handover as you described I would suggest using a webform since vicidial does not play nicely with two Agents haven a lead open at the same time... So if Agent A changes data after initiating the transfer, these changes can/will be lost. On the other hand if Agent A Walks away after leaving the 3-way without properly closing the lead, lead changes from Agent B might be lost when Agent A comes back...

Do not try to use any of the asterisk variables yourself as those will not be passed with any transfers! 
Transfers in Vicidial are nothing more than people entering a conference and the other person leaving!